# Why can't I compile the Ralink wireless driver on 12.04?

Tags: wireless, kernel, compiling, drivers

I'm an ubuntu 12.04 user and my wireless Network card(D-Link WIRELESS N 150 DESKTOP ADAPTER DWA-525) has always worked well with the driver suggested [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsDlink), However this morning I updated the Generic Kernel (as suggested by Upgrade Manager) to version: 3.2.0-26 and suddenly wireless stopped working. It isn't totally unexpected, in fact the following commands *used to* solve the problem:

```
sudo su
  cd /home/jose/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217
make clean
make
make install
  modprobe rt3562sta
exit
```

(Where /home/jose/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217 is the path to the driver)

Unfortunately, Today I got the following error(s) while issuing the **make** step:

```
root@jarvis:/home/jose/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217# make
make -C tools
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/jose/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/jose/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/tools'
/home/jose/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/tools/bin2h
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/jose/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic-pae/build SUBDIRS=/home/jose/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217/os/linux modules
make: *** /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic-pae/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
root@jarvis:/home/jose/DPO_RT3562_3592_3062_LinuxSTA_V2.4.1.1_20101217#
```

I was wondering If somebody knows how to solve this problem? I honestly don't know what to do about it.

Thank you very much in advance for all the help.

J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have the *headers* for the running (or target) kernel installed to be able to build modules. This should solve your problem:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

If you can't get a wired connection, download these two DEB files to a USB stick, etc., and install with `sudo dpkg -i`:

```
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-3.2.0-26_3.2.0-26.41_all.deb
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-3.2.0-26-generic-pae_3.2.0-26.41_i386.deb
```

Comment: Infinite Thanks for your reply, This may sound silly before I ask it, but, Do i Have to install the .DEB files before issuing the install linux headers command? (I just don't want to make any mistakes.) Thanks..

Comment: No -- if you have an internet connection, `apt-get` is all that should be needed. The DEB file *alternative* is only required if you have no connection on the computer and need to use a USB, etc. on another internet-enabled computer...

Comment: @JoseE, please remember to accept the answer (tick/check mark on left) if you are able to successfully compile the driver! :)
Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have an Internet connection on the machine where the problem is happenning. I'm currently writing to you from a Laptop that has windows on it. :(

Comment: And, yep, no problem... let me see If your solution helps.. I'll try it out now. (Things are really slow when internet access is missing)

Comment: THANK YOU izx! That did it pal ! THANK YOU !
Just one thing for the sake of learning, Could you please explain to me What are the Headers? and Why were they missing? (I'm assuming they're usually downloaded with each upgrade, right? not this time... )

Comment: The headers basically contain information which tells the driver (module) how to talk to the kernel. They are *not* be downloaded automatically with each upgrade, but usually if you have the `linux-headers` meta-package installed, they will be upgraded similarly to the actual kernel.